# Passing more than one array to more than one view

Tags: php, codeigniter, view

I'm trying to load a controller wich loads two two different views, and passes a different array to each view.

```
public function index(){
        $this->load->view('Head');

        $data=$this->DAOPromotor->recuperarPromotor();
        $eventos=$this->DAOEvento->recuperarPromotorEventos();
        $this->load->view('MostrarPromotor', $data);
        $this->load->view('MostrarPromotorEventos', $eventos);
        $this->load->view('Footer');
}
```

This is my Controller. Now, the first view ("MostrarPromotor') loads just fine, but the second one keeps throwing an Undefined Variable warning. I've used the recuperarPromotorEventos() method on differnt controllers, and it works just fine. I treat the array the same way on both scripts, but it only works in one.

I'm wondering if maybe it's not possible to have two views reciving data at the same time.

Comment: What `Undefined Variable` do you see?

Comment: Eventos, on the part corresponding to the second view. I figured it out, tho: when I passed the variable $eventos to the view, it broke it down to it's separate parts, using the indexes as references; as none of the indexes were called "eventos", the view couldn't find it.

I don't know how to explain it any better than that, but the fix was changing the $eventos declaration for this:

$eventos["eventos"]=$this->DAOEvento->recuperarPromotorEventos();

Hope that makes my answer a little clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution after looking around some more: when you pass an array to a view, it breaks down said array on its different components, using the index names of the array as references. So, if I had this array:

```
$eventos = array(
   'data1' => 'someData',
   'data2' => 'someMoreData'
);
```

When I pass that array to a view, the view can access the variables $data1 and $data2, but not the $eventos data. As my original array didn't have any index named eventos, there wasn't any variable called that.

As for my particular problem, the only thing I had to do to fix it was to change the code to this:

```
public function index(){
    $this->load->view('Head');

    $data=$this->DAOPromotor->recuperarPromotor();
    $eventos["eventos"]=$this->DAOEvento->recuperarPromotorEventos();
    $this->load->view('MostrarPromotor', $data);
    $this->load->view('MostrarPromotorEventos', $eventos);
    $this->load->view('Footer');
}
```